# Devo commitar meu virtualenv no GitHub?

Tags: python, git, github, virtualenv

Fiz um projeto em Python usando um virtualenv, neste caso devo subir todo o virtualenv para o Github ou apenas o código Python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não recomendo que você envie seu ambiente virtual para seu repositório Git.

Ao invés disso, use o comando `pip freeze` para obter uma lista de todos pacotes utilizados no seu ambiente virtual e salve a saída no arquivo `requirements.txt`. Este arquivo sim, deve ser enviado para seu repositório. Usando `pip install -r requirements.txt` em um ambiente virtual novo, você conseguirá reinstalar todos pacotes necessários ao seu projeto (nas versões corretas inclusive).

O ideal seria configurar um arquivo `.gitignore` na pasta raiz do seu projeto para ignorar os arquivos do ambiente virtual. Se seu ambiente virtual está dentro da pasta `venv` por exemplo, adicione `venv/` no `.gitignore` e salve. Você pode fazer download de um arquivo `.gitignore` bem completo [aqui](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore).